# cuda "invalid argument" error on second kernel

Tags: cuda

I got a problem with kernel launches. I had a program using one big kernel. Now I needed to split it into two due to synchronization issues. The first kernel does some init stuff and gets passed a subset of the arguments passed to the second kernel. Running only the first kernel works fine. Running only the second kernels fails while executing it, due to missing initialization but the kernel itself is started. Running both in a row lets the second kernel fail with an "invalid argument" error. I will provide code if necessary but can't figure out right now how it might help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
here the requested launch code:

```
void DeviceManager::integrate(){
  assert(hostArgs->neighborhoodsSize > 0);
  size_t maxBlockSize;
  size_t blocks;
  size_t threadsPerBlock;
  // init patch kernel
  maxBlockSize = 64;
  blocks = (hostArgs->patchesSize /maxBlockSize);
  if(0 != hostArgs->patchesSize % maxBlockSize){
    blocks++;
  }
  threadsPerBlock = maxBlockSize;
  std::cout << "blocks: " << blocks << ", threadsPerBlock: " << threadsPerBlock << std::endl;
  initPatchKernel<CUDA_MAX_SPACE_DIMENSION><<<blocks,threadsPerBlock>>>(devicePatches, hostArgs->patchesSize);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  //calc kernel
  maxBlockSize = 64;
  blocks = (hostArgs->neighborhoodsSize /maxBlockSize);
  if(0 != hostArgs->neighborhoodsSize % maxBlockSize){
    blocks++;
  }
  threadsPerBlock = maxBlockSize;
  size_t maxHeapSize = hostArgs->patchesSize * (sizeof(LegendreSpace) + sizeof(LinearSpline)) + hostArgs->neighborhoodsSize * (sizeof(ReactionDiffusionCCLinearForm) + sizeof(ReactionDiffusionCCBiLinearForm));
  std::cout << "maxHeapSize: " << maxHeapSize << std::endl;
  cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, maxHeapSize);
  std::cout << "blocks: " << blocks << ", threadsPerBlock: " << threadsPerBlock << std::endl;
  integrateKernel<CUDA_MAX_SPACE_DIMENSION><<<blocks,threadsPerBlock>>>(deviceNeighborhoods, hostArgs->neighborhoodsSize, devicePatches, hostArgs->patchesSize, hostArgs->biLinearForms, hostArgs->linearForms, deviceRes);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

The memory transfers and allocation should not be a problem, since it worked when using only one kernel.

EDIT 2:
I check for errors after each kernel call when building in debug mode via a wrapper function. So after each kernel call the following is executed:

```
cudaError_t cuda_result_code = cudaGetLastError();                        
if (cuda_result_code!=cudaSuccess) {                                      
   fprintf("message: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(cuda_result_code));
}
```

Sorry for not mentioning this, the wrapper is not by me so sorry for not pasting the trick.
The output right before the failure is the following:

```
blocks: 1, threadsPerBlock: 64
maxHeapSize: 4480
blocks: 1, threadsPerBlock: 64
message: invalid argument
```

Comment: I'm sure providing your code would help.  In particular I'd be interested in the launch parameters of your second kernel invocation and how they are derived.

Comment: At least show us your memory init and kernel invocation code..

Comment: I don't see any error checking.  How do you know you're getting a kernel fail with "invalid argument error" ?  Also, immediately before both kernel launches, you are outputting the blocks and threadsPerBlock variables.  What output do you get right before the failure?

Comment: Please add error handling to all cuda* functions not just after launches. I've submitted an answer that I think will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[cudaDeviceSetLimit](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1gb8a22e29cc297634b0702db0b69f59e7)

**cudaLimitMallocHeapSize** controls the size in bytes of the heap used by the malloc() and free() device system calls. Setting cudaLimitMallocHeapSize must be performed **before launching any kernel** that uses the malloc() or free() device system calls, otherwise **cudaErrorInvalidValue** will be returned. This limit is only applicable to devices of compute capability 2.0 and higher. Attempting to set this limit on devices of compute capability less than 2.0 will result in the error cudaErrorUnsupportedLimit being returned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I will try out your suggestion when I got some time which may last some days, sorry for that.

Comment: Now I had the time to check my code with your answer in mind. I had different bugs in my memory allocation design. I now first call cudaDeviceSetLimit (got a card with compute capability 2.0) first than a Kernel to init some memory. Than the main kernel (integrateKernel) which allocs and frees some memory on its own. And finally a new kernel to free the memory initialized by the init kernel (I forgot to do this). Now everything works fine. Thanks a lot again for your answer, you really let me off the hook.